# Make nested markdown tables with asynchronous content stick to the top

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

So I'm trying to create a markdown file for GitHub with nested tables.

This is my code:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th></tr>
<tr><td>

| Name | Num |
| --- | --- |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |


</td><td>

| Name | Num |
| --- | --- |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |
| test123 | 48 |

</td></tr></table>
```

And:

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7SkK.png)

**The question is:** Is it possible to make the left table stick to the top? I want both tables to be at the same height under Header1 and Header2.

I might even add more columns later with different table sizes within and they all should stick to the top.

Comment: I am surprised to see that you can, apparently, place GFM within an [HTML block](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks) (TL;DR). I would not have expected this to work.

Comment: I didn't know either, I just saw someone creating nested tables with this method (different thread) so I tried it myself.

Comment: Please consider posting, and accepting, your answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 1):

The attribute valign="top" fixed my problem. I added it to the  tag of the markdown tables and now the height is correct.